# My screen brightness is too low on Lenovo Thinkpad. Can hardly see what's going on

Tags: screen, brightness

How can I increase the brightness of my laptop screen?
here is the description:

*-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 5500
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:48 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: What model machine?  There are usually function keys to control brightness, what have you tried?

Comment: it's T450s.  I haven't tried any keys other than the one on the keyboard which shows full 100% but still the screen is so dim.